# I want to redirect to a 404 page if did not find an id

Tags: node.js, express

I want to redirect to a 404 page if did not find an id

**page routes/users.js**

```
exports.find = function(req, res) {
       var id =(req.params.id);
     db.getFindById(id,function(err, results){
             if (err) return res.send(500, "DB QUERY ERROR");
             res.render('usr/details', { finds: results });

                                                  });
                                      }
```

**page index.js**

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname +'/views');
    app.set('view engine','jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser({KeepExtensions: true, uploadDir: path.join(__dirname,  '/public/img/user-avatar')}));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(checkDatabase, function(req, res) {res.send(404, "Could not find ")});
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
                      });   


app.get('/list-users/finds/:id',checkDatabase);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add `next` in the parameter list, which Express will pass to your handler. It will move to the next function in the middleware stack.

Then, if no `id` matches, do `return next()` to leave the function and move on to a function that will handle your 404.

```
exports.find = function (req, res, next) {
    var id = (req.params.id);
    db.getFindById(id, function (err, results) {
        // Query failed, note the return to quit the function here.
        if (err) return res.send(500, "DB QUERY ERROR");

        // Move to next function in middleware steck if result set is empty
        if (!results || !results.length) return next();

        // We will not get to this call unless the resultset is populated
        res.render('usr/details', {
            finds: results
        });
    });
}
```

You can then `use` a new function after this one, which will run in the case `next` is called.

```
app.use(user.find, function(req, res) {
   res.send(404, "Could not find ")
};
```

EDIT: What you propably want:

**index.js**

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.bodyParser({
        KeepExtensions: true,
        uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, '/public/img/user-avatar')
    }));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/list-users/finds/:id', user.find, function (req, res) {
    res.send(404, "Could not find ID");
});
```

**routes/users.js**

```
exports.find = function (req, res, next) {
    var id = (req.params.id);
    db.getFindById(id, function (err, results) {
        // Query failed, note the return to quit the function here.
        if (err) return res.send(500, "DB QUERY ERROR");

        // Move to next function in middleware steck if result set is empty
        if (!results || !results.length) return next();

        // We will not get to this call unless the resultset is populated
        res.render('usr/details', {
            finds: results
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError : checkDatabase is not defined

Comment: Of course you would have to replace that with the name of the function above. I don't know what's the variables name you require your exported module to.

Comment: app.configure(function(){
 app.set('views', __dirname +'/views');
 app.set('view engine','jade');
 app.use(express.bodyParser({KeepExtensions: true, uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, '/public/img/user-avatar')}));
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(passport.initialize());
 app.use(checkDatabase, function(req, res) {res.send(404, "Could not find ")});
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

Comment: `checkDatabase` is just a placeholder for your `exports.find` function. How did you pass it to Express earlier?

Comment: app.get('/list-users/finds/:id',user.find);

Comment: Yes. Change `checkDatabse` to `user.find` then ... I also updated the answer.

Comment: same problem wait let me rephrase the question

Comment: I modified the question

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at Object.exports.find [as handle]